# Python can't call functions from separate Python file

Tags: python, selenium

**I want to call these functions from a separate Python file.**

I want to specify the URL in run.py and run the functions from download.py in run.py...

But I keep getting this error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 7, in <module>
    getTumblrPage()
  File "/Users/matt/Python/Instagram Bots/testing/download.py", line 20, in getTumblrPage
    driver.get(url)
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
```

I've tried putting the variables in both files, or just one. Either way, not sure what to do.

Below is download.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib
import base64
import csv
import time

def getTumblrPage():
    driver.get(url)

# If page is infinity scroll, use this method to scrape more photos
def pageScroll():
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    print ('Page scroll 1/5')
    sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    print ('Page scroll 2/5')
    sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    print ('Page scroll 3/5')
    sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    print ('Page scroll 4/5')
    sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    print ('Page scroll 5/5')
    sleep(2)
```

Below is run.py

```
from download import *

url = "https://vjeranski.tumblr.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/matt/Python/chromedriver")

getTumblrPage()
pageScroll()
```

Comment: Python can call the function just fine. The function has an error, though, in that it tries to use a global variable, `driver`, that isn't defined. Python global variables aren't global across the entire process, they are *module global*.

Comment: I suggest you take some time to learn about variable scope and modules in Python. This will help you avoid these mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you're importing `download` into `run`, `download` doesn't have access to variables in `run`.

Instead, make `driver` a parameter of the functions:

```
def pageScroll(driver):
    . . .

def getTumblrPage(driver):
    . . .
```

Then pass it in when you call the functions:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/matt/Python/chromedriver")

getTumblrPage(driver)
pageScroll(driver)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 8, in <module>
    getTumblrPage(driver)
TypeError: getTumblrPage() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @mattwelter you didn't pay attention to how your function is supposed to be defined

Comment: @mattwelter Yes, note the first block of code I posted. You need to give the functions each a parameter (the name within `()`s). If you aren't familiar with parameters, I would look into them unless you're currently in the middle of studying something else. They are fairly fundamental to programming, and you will need to have a good understanding of them to write Python (or really any language).